# Navbar becomes sticky when scrolling up even 1px - I want it to appear only when scrolling more than 10px

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a navbar that is always sticky on mobile and disappears when scrolling down but appears again when scrolling up on desktop.

Now it works perfectly well but I have one problem. On desktop, it becomes sticky when scrolling up right away. Even if I scroll just a little bit which can be annoying.

[image]

I want it to appear only when scrolling more than let's say 10px. So I'd need to add some threshold. I guess it could be done with JS but I'm a beginner.

Here's a fiddle with what I have now: https://jsfiddle.net/zsoltszilvai/zfqd901m/4/

I'd appreciate any help :)

```
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;

function myFunction(x) {
  if (x.matches) {

    window.onscroll = function() {
      var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
    }

  } else {
    window.onscroll = function() {
      var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
      if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
        if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
          header.classList.add("sticky");
        }
      } else {
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-58px";
        if (window.pageYOffset < sticky) {
          header.classList.remove("sticky");
        }
      }
      prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos` to `prevScrollpos - currentScrollPos > 10`, only tricky part is to not update prevScrollpos if the difference is smaller than the threshold.

```
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
var SCROLL_UP_THRESHOLD = 200

function myFunction(x) {
  window.onscroll = function() {
    var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
    console.log(prevScrollpos, currentScrollPos)
    if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
      if (prevScrollpos - currentScrollPos < SCROLL_UP_THRESHOLD) 
        return console.log("not opening")
      document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
      if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
        header.classList.add("sticky");
      }
      prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-58px";
      if (window.pageYOffset < sticky) {
        header.classList.remove("sticky");
      }
      prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi!  Thanks a lot for your answer. It does solve the problem on desktop but it also creates one on mobile. The header on mobile is now not sticky and does some pretty weird stuff when opening the hamburger menu.
https://jsfiddle.net/zsoltszilvai/Lx4tvsb6/12/

Comment: Here's a gif of the behaviour now: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zMuaUaTV8C9xf5UiMKWHLdvFjpK8Fb1G/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Just an update: your solution actually works perfectly, I just had to make sure I had all the "else" statements in the right place: https://jsfiddle.net/zsoltszilvai/Lx4tvsb6/15/

Thanks a lot, I appreciate your help :)